# Problema com download de ficheiro PDF com laravel

Tags: laravel, download

Tenho um sistema para fazer download de ficheiros PDF, o que está acontecer e que tento fazer download, e simplesmente não faz download.
Já vi no pelo inspector do chromo e não da nenhum erro.

**Controller**

```
class DownloadController extends Controller{

    public function getDownload (){

      $filename = 'certificacoes/teste.pdf';
      $path = storage_path($filename);

      return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
          'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
      ]);
    }
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '#download_link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var creditos = {{$creditos}}

    if(creditos == 0){
      sweetAlert("Erro...", 'Não tem créditos disponiveis. Efectue upload de uma certificação', "error");
    }else{

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/download',
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          //data: formData
      }).done(function(response) {

      }).fail(function(data) {
          sweetAlert("Erro...", 'Ocorreu um erro ao efectuar o download. Por favor tente novamente!', "error");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou acessar a *URL* direto sem ser por *Ajax* ?

Comment: Algumas sugestões e casos que podem ocasionar isso...

1. Confere as permissões das pastas e dos arquivos.
2. As rotas estão corretas, chamando a função do `Controller` e enviando a resposta? Faz um console.log no `ajax` e retorna uma resposta simples pra ver se está tudo certo nesse processo.
3. O seu `Response` está sendo adicionado no inicio do arquivo?
4. Já tentou usar uma biblioteca para fazer isso de forma mais simples?
Indico o [DOMPDF][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score -1):

Usar o Ajax para fazer o download dos arquivos não é a melhor forma. Por medida de segurança você não pode salvar um arquivo no computador do usuário utilizando javascript. Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guia/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_ao_JavaScript.

> JavaScript
>
> Não pode escrever automaticamente no disco rígido.

O que você pode fazer é redirecionar o usuário para a URL de download.

```
window.location = 'URL_DOWNLOAD';
```

**Se quiser melhorar a forma como seu controller cria a resposta de download**, de acordo com a documentação do Laravel [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#other-response-types), você pode enviar uma resposta de download de duas formas:

Dessa forma quando a URL for acessada o navegador vai iniciar um download

```
return response()->download($path, $name, $headers);
// OU
return Response::download($path, $name, $headers);
```

Utilizando essa forma ao acessar a URL o navegador vai tentar abrir o arquivo ao invés de realizar o download direto

```
return response()->file($path);
//OU
return Response::file($path);
```